# HTML import: CustomTag not registered

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to create a custom element from `polymer-element`, but I cannot make the `@CustomTag` work. My `dart` file (`my_element.dart`) looks like this:

```
@HtmlImport('my_element.html')
library projects.projectFolder.layout;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

  @published String caption;
  MyElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

My `html` file (`my_element.html`) looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element"> 
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_element.css">

    <core-toolbar>
      <h1>{{ caption }}</h1>
    </core-toolbar>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="../my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The thing is that the Chrome console keeps on printing the following error:

```
No elements registered in a while, but still waiting on 1 elements to be registered. Check that you have a class with an @CustomTag annotation for each of the following tags: 'my-element'.
```

It's curious, because I have declared the custom tag as it should be. It looks like it hasn't read the `.dart` file when it reaches the `.html`.
The `.html` file is called from another parent `.html` file. I think that the order in which the files are called could be the problem, but then again if Dart is compiled before running, it shouldn't care.
I have tried several solutions but none of them have worked. The only one that worked is pretty dirty one, which is importing the `my_element.dart` file straight from the main `my_app.dart` file. I guess it shouldn't be done that way because that would mean to import every single `my_element.dart` file in the same main `my_app.dart`.

**EDIT (add `index.html`, `pubspec.yml`)**
My `index.html` file looks like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>My app</title>
</head>
<body unresolved fullbleed>
  <my-app></my-app>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'package:project/my_app.dart';

    main() => initPolymer();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`my_app` is another custom element, which is the main element where all the others go. In other words, it is like the main controller for the app. This element has a `.dart` and `.html` file as well, which will call other elements like `my-element`.
As you can see, my `main()` function is very simple, since it only init Polymer (see `index.html`).

My `pubspec.yml` looks like following:

```
name: project
version: 0.0.1
description: Some project.
author: Tomas
homepage: https://github.com/*******

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.10.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  polymer: '^0.16.0'
  core_elements: '^0.7.1'
  paper_elements: '^0.7.1'
  route_hierarchical: "^0.6.1"

transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- $dart2js:
    $include: "**/*.polymer.bootstrap.dart"
```

My directory looks like this (I just show a fraction of it, the important one I hope):

```
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   └── web
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── index.html.polymer.bootstrap.dart.js
│       └── packages
├── lib
│   ├── my_app.dart
│   └── src
│       ├── elements
│       ├── layout
│       │   ├── my_element.css
│       │   ├── my_element.dart
│       │   └── my_element.html
│       ├── my_app.css
│       ├── my_app.html
│       └── modules
│           └── module.dart
│       ├── my_app.css
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
└── web
│   ├── index.html
│   └── packages -> ../packages
│       ├── my_app.html
│       └── modules
│           └── module.dart
```

I hope that this edit doesn't confuse more than it should. I'm just looking to know which is the correct folder structure and import form of a Dart app.

In short terms: how should the tree look like when programming a big application in dart, and where should I do the imports? I have look at every documentation I could, including some tutorials, but all of them talk about very simple examples where the big part of the code is in the `web` folder, which I wouldn't want.

**EDIT (summarize and rephrase, add `my_app.html` and `my_app.dart`)**

In fewer words:

I've a custom element defined by `my_element.html` and `my_element.dart` (defined above in this answer) and I want to import it into another `my_app` element using only the html. I.e. not by importing `my_element.dart` in `my_app.dart`, but by only importing `my_element.html` using a link tag in `my_app.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="layout/my_element.html">

<polymer-element name="my-app">
  <template>

    <core-scaffold id="scaffold">

      <my-element tool flex></my-element>

      <main fit></main>

    </core-scaffold>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="../my_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

`my_app.dart`:

```
@HtmlImport('src/my_app.html')

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_scaffold.dart';

@CustomTag('my-app')
class MyApp extends PolymerElement {

  MyApp.created() : super.created();
}
```

Shouldn't the `<script type="application/dart" src="../my_element.dart"></script>` be enough to tell the compiler to load that dart file for registering the element tag by following the transitive dependence defined by the html import?

Comment: How does your `main()`, `index. html`, and `pubspec.yaml` look like? In which directory are your element files?

Comment: I just did an edit to the question where I show the informations requested. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Just to confirm, does your `my_app.dart` file import your `my_element.dart` file?

Comment: No... when I did it it worked. I actually knew that it can be done that way. If I import `my_element.dart` in `my_app.dart` everything should work. The thing is that if I ever have several custom elements (let's say 50), then I'll will have to import them one by one, which I guess is not the proper way of doing it. I saw recently a solution where they had a file with all the necessary imports, and then they would import that file, but then again, I don't think it's a "clean" way. I'm looking for the proper (hopefully, very clean) way of doing this.

Comment: I actually said it in the question (I just did an small edit). 
I said that if I do an import straight from the main, then it'll work. But the reason I don't like it is because I would have some many imports eventually.

Comment: Is it enough to import my_element.html by using a link tag in my_app.html? Shouldn't the dart file be imported by specifying the script tag in my_element.html?

Comment: I think you'll just have to accept that it has to be imported, unless you want to try a solution with Mirrors API.  Ultimately a long list of imports isn't the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import all your custom component Dart classes in your `my_app.dart`.  Typically you'd create a single Dart file to import, which would export each entry so that your `my_app.dart` stays clean.